# Tag synonym: indent->indentation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[indent](/questions/tagged/indent) and [indentation](/questions/tagged/indentation) not only both exist and are in active use, their tag wikis differ by a single word (probably because the system rejected identical wikis).  They should be merged.

Comment: +1 for this, can't suggest because I don't have reputation for the tag